# RegEnumKeyExW not return all name sub-keys

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I want to enumerate name of key. but. is there something wrong here. it don't return all name. i checks subKeys it return 12 total Keys. when loop in **RegEnumKeyExW** it only return 3 name not 12 name. it only return 1,2 and 5 name key

in key **HKEY_CURRENT_USER**. there're **12** Keys.

1. AppEvents
2. Console
3. Control  Panel
4. Environment
5. EUDC
6. Identities
7. Keyboard Layout
8. Network
9. Printers
10. Software
11. System
12. Volatile Environment

This the code

```
HKEY hKey;
    if (RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, NULL, 0, KEY_READ, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        DWORD subKeys;
        FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;
        if (RegQueryInfoKeyW(hKey, NULL, NULL, NULL, &subKeys, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &ftLastWriteTime) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            wchar_t keyName[MAX_KEY_LENGTH];
            DWORD cbName;
            for (DWORD i = 0; i < subKeys; i++)
            {
                if (RegEnumKeyExW(hKey, i, keyName, &cbName, NULL, NULL, NULL, &ftLastWriteTime) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
                {
                        std::wcout << keyName << std::endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: Try to open key with fewer rights, `RegEnumKeyExW` only requires `KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS`. You don't need to call `RegQueryInfoKeyW` first, just loop until `RegEnumKeyExW` fails.

Comment: at first Reg api not set `GetLastError()` but return error code. at second - your error in not initialize **`cbName`** in call `RegEnumKeyExW`. this is in-out parameter and before call must specifies the size of the buffer specified by the `lpName` parameter, in characters. so must be `&(cbName = RTL_NUMBER_OF(keyName))` in your code

Comment: When an API function does not behave as expected you must re-read the documentation. One of the things you will there is how the error handling is performed for this function, and indeed all the registry api functions.

Comment: Fix: DWORD cbName = MAX_KEY_LENGTH;  Right now it works by accident for the first subkey and can only work again when the name is shorter.  So indeed 1, 2 and 5.

Answer (score 1):

As @Hans Passant says, You should reset the length of `cbName`, But actually not the `MAX_KEY_LENGTH`. If the buff length is not enough for the key name, `RegEnumKeyExW` will get failure. Add parameter in `RegQueryInfoKeyW` above to get the max length of the subkey name:

```
DWORD cbMaxSubKeyLen;
if (RegQueryInfoKeyW(hKey, NULL, NULL, NULL, &subKeys, &cbMaxSubKeyLen, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &ftLastWriteTime) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
```

Then in the for loop, reset the `cbName = cbMaxSubKeyLen;`

Comment: It is okay to query for the size.  But then it is also very, very, very important to reallocate keyName so it is big enough.  Buffer overflow is quite a nasty bug.